# Always losing (Discordjs V12)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a bot in discord.js v12 and I made a piece of code for the bank. I made random coins but the problem is that I always lose coins and never receive/gain.

I want to make it so you lost or gain. Here is my code:

```js
if (message.content === '.randomcoins') {
  let currentBalance = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`);
  let randomc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  var what = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
  if (what === '1') {
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, currentBalance + randomc);
    message.channel.send(`You recived ${randomc} Coins.`);
  } else {
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, currentBalance - randomc);
    message.channel.send(`You lost ${randomc} Coins.`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're checking if the variable `what` is equal to the string `"1"` but `what` is always an integer so only the `else` block runs. The number `1` and the string `"1"` is not the same thing.

Make sure you check if `what === 1` instead and it will work properly:

```js
if (message.content === '.randomcoins') {
  let currentBalance = await db.get(`wallet_${message.author.id}`);
  let randomc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  var what = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
  if (what === 1) {
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, currentBalance + randomc);
    message.channel.send(`You recived ${randomc} Coins.`);
  } else {
    await db.set(`wallet_${message.author.id}`, currentBalance - randomc);
    message.channel.send(`You lost ${randomc} Coins.`);
  }
}
```